# MariaDB Permission denied when using socket

Tags: mysql, php, centos5, mariadb

Here is the gist of my problem:  I have a web application that won't connect when the database has the host is set as localhost, however it will if I use the address 127.0.0.1.  The error that PHP gives me when connecting is: "SQLSTATE[HY000][2002] Permission denied".  I know that the socket is there because when I stop the service I get "SQ:STATE[HY000][2002] No such file or directory."

After I type in "ls -als /tmp" in the terminal, I see that mysql.sock has the permissions of 777.

Any ideas why I cannot connect to the socket?

Answer (score 1):

Does your `mysql.user` table have an entry for your database user for `localhost` host? If not, that is the reason for `Permission denied` error from MySQL.

Comment: Yes, it does have an entry for the user for localhost.

Comment: Have you checked PHP's configuration that it tries to use the socket in `/tmp/mysql.sock`? Can you connect to MariaDB using `mysql -u user@localhost -p` and entering the password?

Comment: I've manually edited the php.ini file to point to /tmp/mysql.sock.  No, I cannot connect using ```mysql -u user@localhost -p```.

Comment: I am thinking it may have something to do with SELinux on CentOS

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS, the culprit is SELinux
You can confirm by running the command

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

Check if httpd_can_network_connect_db is Off.
If it is off you can enable it using the command

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

(The -P flag makes the change permanent, so the setting survives a reboot.)

> Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475776/6000657